# How to set the data to the class and read it back?

Tags: jquery

To avoid usage of global variables , I am trying to set the data to the class and read it back .
but as a result i am getting it back as `[Object , Object]` and when i tried to stringify that i am getting as `{}`

http://jsfiddle.net/oeufafed/2/

This is my code

```
<div id="section">
<form class="myformcalss">
London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom
</form>
</div>

$('#section').find('.myformcalss').data('sample data');
var text = $('#section').find('.myformcalss').data();
//var result = JSON.stringify(text);
alert(text);
```

Could you please let me know how to set and read the data back ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `key`

```
$('#section').find('.myformcalss').data('key', 'sample data');

var text = $('#section').find('.myformcalss').data('key');
```

for set some data

```
.data('key', 'value');
```

for get some data

```
.data('key');
```

> key
>
> Type: String,
>
> A string naming the piece of data to set.

>
>
>

> value
>
> Type: Anything,
>
> The new data value; this can be any Javascript type
>   except undefined.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/oeufafed/3/)